Bulk download files from S3
Is there a way to bulk download s3 files?
I have a list of files I want to download. I am currently using the download_file() method which is called in a loop--see sample usage below. Wanted to know if there was an alternative way.
    def download_files(dir: str, keys: List[str]):
            for key in keys:
                file_path = os.path.join(dir, key)
                self.client.download_file(bucket_name, key, file_path)


S3 has no API to get multiple objects with one request, so this is pretty much the only solution.  You can add multi-threading or multi-processing to download in parallel, but the exact implementation will depend on your project's needs.

Use asyncio to download in parallel
